# SwiftUI — How can I display a countdown in a ScrollView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-6

I'm trying to make a SwiftUI app for Apple Watch that requires a countdown timer within a ScrollView. However, when I put a date formatter in a ScrollView, the app crashes (at least in the Simulator — I can't test on a real device because I have reached my app ID limit for a few days).

The code looks like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(date, style: .timer)
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives me this runtime error: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Within a function called `SwiftUI.DisplayList.ViewUpdater.ViewCache.setNextUpdate(_:item:state:tag:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a bug it seems worthy of a report.

`DateFormatter()` seems to be a viable workaround.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimerStyle: View {
    let date = Date()
    
    let timerFormat: DateFormatter
    
    init() {
        timerFormat = DateFormatter()
        timerFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        
    }
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(date, formatter: timerFormat)
        }
    }
}

struct TimerStyle_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimerStyle()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer!!! just add

.clipped()

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(Date(), style: .timer)
                .clipped()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this is the asnwer.

Comment: This is a magic bug,I don't know how it works

Comment: For anybody experiencing this issue, I recommend upgrading to at least iOS 14.2 using `@available(iOS 14.2, *)`, as using versions 14.1 or 14.0 will cause crashes when nest Text.timer in ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(Date(), style: .timer)
                .clipped()
        }
    }
}
```